# Control MIME structure of emails produced with cfmail

Tags: coldfusion

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047950/multiple-attachments-to-an-html-email-different-mail-clients) I asked about what the structure of the email *should* be.  This question is about how to use cfmail (and cfmailpart, cfmailparam, etc.) to produce the correct structure.

The desired structure is:

```
multipart/mixed
  multipart/alternative
    text/plain
    text/html
  image/jpeg
  application/pdf
```

The code I've got currently:

```
 <cfmail from='"No Reply" <noreply@example.com>' subject="Test 123" to="my_outlook_address@example.com,my_gmail_address@gmail.com">

  <!--- Some code to get a query of attachment content here... --->

  <cfloop query="qAttachments">
      <!---
          Some code to get the attachment file data here and put it in a variable named `myfile`... 

          myfile structure:
          {
              fileName: <string>,
              fileContent: <base64 encoded file content>,
              mimeType: <image/jpeg for the one, application/pdf for the other>
          }
      --->
      <cfmailparam disposition="attachment" contentID="#myfile.fileName#" content="#myfile.fileContent#" file="#myfile.fileName#" type="#myfile.mimeType#" />

  </cfloop>

  <cfmailpart type="plain">
      My plain text
  </cfmailpart>

  <cfmailpart type="html">
      <strong>My fancypants text</strong>
  </cfmailpart>
</cfmail>
```

However, this produces this structure:

```
multipart/mixed
  multipart/alternative
    text/plain
    multipart/related
      text/html
      image/jpeg
      application/pdf
```

I've tried code like this:

```
<cfmail from='"No Reply" <noreply@example.com>' subject="Test 123" to="my_outlook_address@example.com,my_gmail_address@gmail.com">

  <!--- Some code to get a query of attachment content here... --->

  <cfloop query="qAttachments">       
      <cfmailparam disposition="attachment" contentID="#myfile.fileName#" content="#myfile.fileContent#" file="#myfile.fileName#" type="#myfile.mimeType#" />

  </cfloop>

  <cfmailpart type="multipart/alternative">
    <cfmailpart type="plain">
      My plain text
    </cfmailpart>

    <cfmailpart type="html">
      <strong>My fancypants text</strong>
    </cfmailpart>
  </cfmailpart>
</cfmail>
```

But then it just goes to the undelivered email list in cfadmin.

With both versions of the code I tried for values of the `type` attribute on the `cfmail` tag itself:

- plain
- html
- multipart/mixed
- multipart/alternative

to no avail.

How do I achieve the desired MIME structure in ColdFusion?

Comment: Discussing with a coworker brought up a good point - that ColdFusion provides an abstraction of the java mail capabilities.  It may be this abstraction is opinionated in a way that limits it to not being suitable for the use case I'm looking at.

Comment: Also, cfmail has a default "type" (mime type) which may be skewing the result.

Comment: @Ageax ah, right.  I forgot to mention in the question that I'd tried different things there as well.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Did you look in the [bug tracker](https://tracker.adobe.com)? While I don't know the answer, I'm sure I've seen other issues with cfmailparam and mime types over the years...

Comment: @Ageax I hadn't, but this one looks particularly related https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4166939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach I landed on may not be ideal, but it works in all 3 mail clients I was targeting.  What I ended up doing was this:

- for any image attachments, I would include a `contentID` attribute on the `cfmailparam` tag and include an `<img src="cid:...">` with the `contentID` value
- for all other attachments, I omit the `contentID` attribute on the `cfmailparam` tag

This has the end result that all images are presented inline in the message body, and all other files are displayed as regular file attachments.

Based on the discussion by who I assume is a developer on the CF team here https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4166939 I'm under the impression that the MIME header structure is controlled by ColdFusion and isn't directly manageable by ColdFusion developers.  Unfortunate, but at least I have something of a workaround.  Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering about the cid! I've never seen it used for anything other than embedded images. Wonder if it's actually valid for other file types or attachments? Time to surf the RFC's ;-)